# Trying to use Google OAuth from a Kubernetes pod gets run_local_server() hang

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, flask, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I took the code snippet of getting authentication and authorization to google sheets and drive from the snippets on the web

```
    user_token_filename = f'{username}_token.json'
creds = None
logger.warning(f"Trying to see if {user_token_filename} exists, creds is {creds}")
if os.path.exists(user_token_filename):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(user_token_filename, SCOPES)
    logger.warning(f"File exists - read {creds} from it")
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
try:
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        logger.warning(f"No creds, no file")
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
            logger.warning("Flow ready to create local server")
            creds = flow.run_local_server(bind_addr="0.0.0.0")
            logger.warning(f"Going to write {creds.to_json()} into {user_token_filename}")
            with open(user_token_filename, 'w') as token:
                token.write(creds.to_json())
except HttpError as herr:
    logger.error(f"Failed with HttpError = {herr}")
    raise
except Exception as err:
    logger.error(f"Failed with genericError = {err}")
    raise
logger.warning("Done with sheets authorization")
return user_token_filename, creds
```

Running this code locally (with Edge/Chrome as the frontend for my Flask application) works great. But after deploying the app to a pod running inside Kubernetes, the line with `flow.run_local_host()` never returns and after 30 seconds the page gets a timeout.

Any idea?